# Compiler error: Type mismatch when assigned interface variable to a class

Tags: java

I have a strange problem i don't know if i miss something. Here is my code

```
public interface Book{
}

public class MyBook implements Book
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Book b = new MyBook();  // compiler error: Type mismatch ....
}
```

Can somebody explains to me is this really a compiler error or just my eclipse is acting weird?

Thanks,

Comment: Show us the entire class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is another interface of exact same name that is in the imported statement that is causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your main method is not in a class, try putting it inside a class.

Also make sure to have only one public class per Java file.

Answer (score 0):

I think after implementation of interface you can make object of class that implemented interface so make the object of class "MyBook"